# Help with out of control text in html

Tags: css, html

We are trying to make a web-page for a competition in synthetic biology and have a small problem on our page: http://2011.igem.org/Team:DTU-Denmark-2/Project/PlugnplayAssembly/customization

As you can see the text goes beyond our frame, i think it has something to do with the css menu we made, but i have no idea what to do about it. you code can be found here:

http://2011.igem.org/wiki/index.php?title=Team:DTU-Denmark-2/Project/PlugnplayAssembly/customization&action=edit

We hope you can help us out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've set the menu with a width of 200px, (however under firebug its showing at 500px for some reason) and the text with a width of 75%.

Try changing the menu to 25% or a fixed value to both Td's (menu and content).

Comment: when setting the menu to 25% or fixing values for both menu and content nothing changes. It is if the width is not even used

Comment: I see this is in some kind of CMS. I bet you that yoru values are being over written by something else.